# How to set up rewrite rule in Azure Web App - Linux

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have an Azure Web App running on linux and i want to set up a rewrite rule for my application. When users visit `example.com`, i will redirect them to `www.example.com`.

In windows, it is easier to use `web.config` but how is it done in Linux ?

On the linux, there is no `Apache` or `Nginx` installed but i am wondering how the application is running.

How can i get this done ? Set up a rewrite rule on either Apache or Nginx to affect my Azure Web App running on linux ?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: Same here , i have a Linux based Azure Web App. ASP.net isn't part of the tech stack for my hosting. We are using React and Next.js. I also don't see any Apache server folders where I normally add in the url rewrites.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this as we have the exact same issue?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, your needs can be solved in two ways.

[For more details, you can read this blogs](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Mar/13/Back-to-Basics-Rewriting-a-URL-in-ASPNET-Core#the-aspnet-core-rewrite-middleware-module).

And also can download sample code([ASP.NET Core URL Rewriting Sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/url-rewriting/samples/3.x/SampleApp))to test it.

**The first method:**

*Re-Writing a URL*

Here's how to handle a Rewrite operation in app.Use() middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context,next) =>
{
    var url = context.Request.Path.Value;

    // Redirect to an external URL
    if (url.Contains("/home/privacy")) // you can use equal
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("https://markdownmonster.west-wind.com")
        //return;   // short circuit
    }

    await next();
});
```

**The second method:**

[The ASP.NET Core Rewrite Middleware Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.0#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware)

[image]

The above two methods are officially provided. The actual test needs to be deployed to Azure for testing. If you have any questions, you can also [raise a support ticket for help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: How is the above solution helpful for the op? He stated he is using Linux not IIS and Windows, your solution is pointing to a Windows ASP.Net solution?

Comment: @JeepersCreepers This is handled from the application, you can first learn ASP.NET CORE Middleware.